# Trouble converting an XML string into an object

Tags: php, xml, xml-namespaces

The string below is returned as part of an object from an API.

```
public 'schema' => string '<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Table1"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="SblID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="SroID" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="SroName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:e'... (length=1434)
```

I want to interpret this string as an abject.

I started with following which seems logical

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($resultstring) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

print_r($xml);
```

However the output contains only the first element

**SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => NewDataSet ) )**

Any ideas as to how I can view the entire string as an object would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping some error processing around the `simplexml_load_string()` See this manual page for some assistance  http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php Alternatively look in php_error.log as `simplexml_load_string` is supposed to `Produces an E_WARNING error message for each error found in the XML data. `

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Apologies to everyone envolved, the returning XML string didn't contain any data, so my original code was working fine, just had nothing to show.

Sorry!

Thanks